# Django PasswordResetConfirmView not setting new password

Tags: django

I am trying to use a Custom PasswordResetConfirmView template.

Since the default form has no styling and I am trying to put a custom class in it.

Here is my `forms.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm

class UserPasswordChangeForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserPasswordChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    new_password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Password',
    }))
    new_password2 = forms.CharField(label='Conform Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Confirm Password',
    }))
```

Here is `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
 auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_confirm.html', form_class=UserPasswordChangeForm, success_url=reverse_lazy('password_reset_complete')),
 name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

When I put `new_password1` and `new_password2`, it does not save the new password, or even show erorrs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You inherit from the wrong form class. `PasswordResetConfirmView` uses the form class `SetPasswordForm` while you are inheriting from `PasswordChangeForm` which has an extra field for the old password (does not make sense here, user has forgotten the password...). Change your implementation to inherit correctly:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import SetPasswordForm


class UserSetPasswordForm(SetPasswordForm):
    # your modifications
```

And your urls:

```
path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/',
 auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='registration/password_reset_confirm.html', form_class=UserSetPasswordForm, success_url=reverse_lazy('password_reset_complete')),
 name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

Comment: That worked. I searched `forms.py` in the `django\contrib\auth` folder, and god knows how I missed it and picked the wrong form.